# Was it possible to do a course correction on the planned manned Venus flyby?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, venus, flyby

> Once the burn was complete, any remaining propellant would be vented to space, and then the larger fuel tank could be used as living space, while the smaller oxygen tank would be used for waste storage.

It was planned that after they were on a trajectory to get to Venus they would empty the fuel tanks for more living space. Was there any backup system in case a course correction was needed or would the astronauts not be able to return to Earth?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manned_Venus_flyby

Comment: Does the last line second paragraph of the background section in the link ' These engines would have been responsible for both course correction during the flight and the braking burn for Earth re-entry. ' answer your question?

Comment: @GremlinWranger oops- I overlooked that